# SymmetricAlgorithm GenerateKey with 128 bit

Tags: c#, cryptography, symmetric-key

I have the following code to create a new `SymmetricAlgorithm`:

```
internal static SymmetricAlgorithm CreateSymmetricAlgorithm()
{
    var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 128,
        Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    };
    return algorithm;
}
```

I use the code like:

```
var algorithm = SymmetricHelper.CreateSymmetricAlgorithm();
var key = algorithm.GenerateKey();
```

But the generated-key-size is just 16 `Byte`.

Why I don't get a Key with 128-Bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 bytes *is* 128 bit, 16 * 8 = 128.